# How can I move my solution from a shared folder to my local computer?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to move my solution from a shared folder to my local computer. 
I did a simple copy/paste but the references somehow broke.
Can anybody help me to do a proper "export"?

[Thisis the problem that i got with references. (Methods, classes,... are whited-out)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xcW4.png)

FIXED - I just closed all windows and reopened them and the problem mentioned above dissapeared..., so the solution that worked for me is the John's one, just copy/paste the complete solution directory to my local folder. 
Thanks John, thanks JonasH.

Comment: If your references broke then there's probably a problem with your project.

Comment: You mean that a simple copy/paste of the solution should work?

Comment: If you copy the folder that the solution is contained within, I would expect it to work. At worst you might have to restore NuGet packages. You can pull pretty much any C# project off GitHub, etc. and you should typically be able to build it without issues.

Comment: I just added a photo so you can view the problem i'm facing while trying to do it this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that some of your projects are using absolute paths to references or other dependencies. Reference paths should be relative to the project file to avoid these kinds of problems.

This can be checked by opening the .csproj files in a text editor and looking for

```
<Reference Include="SomeDll">
  <HintPath>c:\SomePath\SomeDll.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This should be replaced with a relative path, like this

```
<Reference Include="SomeDll">
  <HintPath>..\SomePath\SomeDll.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

There is unfortunately not any automated way to do this that I know of, so you might need to do it by hand.

This also means that references needs to be placed in the same folder as the solution. Typically in something like a library folder. If references are relative, but point outside the solution-folder, then you will not be able to move just the solution folder.

It might also be that there are some third party dependencies that need to be installed separately on the new computer.

Comment: These are relative?    '<Reference Include="System.IO.Packaging, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\System.IO.Packaging.4.0.0\lib\net46\System.IO.Packaging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>'

Comment: OR there are referenced projects OUTSIDE the solution that are referenced relative - and not copied to the local location.